# How can I add a SUM clause for a certain variable to a WHERE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I am using SQL Server view design:

```sql
SELECT
    RaceDateTime, Meeting, Horse, Jockey, Trainer, CardNumber,
    Result, [WinSP ], Going, Furlongs, Prize, 
FROM
    dbo.[RACE-TEMPLATE]
WHERE
    (1 = 1) AND
    (BetfairSP_Rank = 1) AND
    (YEAR(RaceDateTime) > 2016) AND
    (Furlongs <= 8) AND
    (Jockey = 'Smith')
```

The above is a sample of the program which is run as is. I also want to add an additional output figure.

```sql
SUM [WinSP ] of all cases where 'Result' = 1
```

Then report the title as follows.

```
COUNT (TOTAL RECORDS) COUNT (Results = 1)  SUM ([WinSP ] of all cases where 'Result' = 1)
```

Comment: Seems you are after a windowed conditional `COUNT`? Sample data and expected results would really help us help you here.

Comment: FYI `(YEAR(RaceDateTime) > 2016)` is not SARGable and therefore should be avoided in the `WHERE`. Use a date range: `RaceDateTime >= '20160101' AND RaceDateTime < '20170101'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a windowed conditional counts and sums. Windowing uses the `OVER` clause, in this case it seems you just want `OVER ()`.

```sql
SELECT
    RaceDateTime, Meeting, Horse, Jockey, Trainer, CardNumber,
    Result, [WinSP ], Going, Furlongs, Prize, 
    TotalCount    = COUNT(*) OVER (),
    Results1Count = COUNT(CASE WHEN Results = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (),
    Results1WinSP = SUM(CASE WHEN Results = 1 THEN WinSP END) OVER ()
FROM
    dbo.[RACE-TEMPLATE]
WHERE
    (1 = 1) AND
    (BetfairSP_Rank = 1) AND
    (RaceDateTime >= '20160101' AND RaceDateTime < '20170101') AND
    (Furlongs <= 8) AND
    (Jockey = 'Smith')
;
```

Note also the use of a proper date range, rather than using the `YEAR` function, as it means the server can properly utilize indexes.

Comment: Thank you Charlieface, it worked a treat.

Comment: I suggest you make a new question for that. But you should be able to do that yourself already given what I've shown you.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance Charlieface but I'm new on here and almost no experience of coding. I would like to try to do a report but I'd better ask a new question. Is the format of my question okay or do I need to modify it ?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help more to understand requirements. Even better: make a full `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` script so we can reproduce it. https://dbfiddle.uk is very good for this.

Comment: Format preferred  BET P/L ROI WINS S/R
                             220 22 10.0% 110 50.0% doesn't work on here but data should be underneath headers

Comment: Hi Charlieface, Just to confirm I was able to follow your advice and created those extra columns. Thanks again for your assistance. It wasn't that difficult after all. Ian

Answer (score 0):

You can precalculate the sums and counts in a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) by using use a [CASE expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql).

```sql
WITH Sums_CTE (CountRecords, Count1Results, Sum1ResultWinSPs)
AS
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS CountRecords,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count1Results,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN WinSP ELSE 0 END) AS Sum1ResultWinSPs
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    Sums_CTE.CountRecords, Sums_CTE.Count1Results, Sums_CTE.Sum1ResultWinSPs,
    RaceDateTime, Meeting, Horse, Jockey, Trainer, CardNumber,
    Result, [WinSP ], Going, Furlongs, Prize
FROM
    Sums_CTE 
    CROSS JOIN dbo.[RACE-TEMPLATE]
WHERE
    (1 = 1) AND
    (BetfairSP_Rank = 1) AND
    (YEAR(RaceDateTime) > 2016) AND
    (Furlongs <= 8) AND
    (Jockey = 'Smith')
```

Comment: Not sure where to start but will have a think tomorrow.